# QueryDSL how to add ParamExpression to JPAQuery to be executed with EntityManager.createQuery

Tags: java, querydsl

---

Hi, I'd like to create JPA query with parameters using QueryDSL, the code is like

```
private static JPAQuery<Tuple> projectionQuery(JPAQuery<?> query, QCoupon qCoupon, QCouponApplication qCouponApplication) {
        return query.select(
                qCoupon.id,
                qCoupon.code,
                qCoupon.status,
                qCoupon.amount,
                qCoupon.benefitType,
                qCoupon.maxDiscountPerApplication,
                qCoupon.additionalMonth,
                qCouponApplication.count().as("usedQuota"),
                qCoupon.globalQuota,
                qCoupon.basePriceOnly
        );
    }

public GetCouponsResponseDTO getCouponsRewrited(String code, ZonedDateTime startCreatedDate, ZonedDateTime endCreatedDate, CouponStatus status, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
        QCoupon qCoupon = QCoupon.coupon;
        QCouponApplication qCouponApplication = QCouponApplication.couponApplication;
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize);
        JPAQuery<?> query =
                        projectionQuery(new JPAQuery<>(), qCoupon, qCouponApplication)
                        .from(qCoupon).leftJoin(qCoupon.applications, qCouponApplication)
                        .groupBy(qCoupon)
                        .orderBy(new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.DESC, qCoupon.createdAt));

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(code)) {
            ParamExpression<String> codeParam = new ParamExpressionImpl<>(String.class);
            query = query.where(qCoupon.code.likeIgnoreCase(codeParam)).set(codeParam, '%' + code + '%');
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(startCreatedDate)) {
            ParamExpression<ZonedDateTime> createdAtParam = new ParamExpressionImpl<>(ZonedDateTime.class);
            query = query.where(qCoupon.createdAt.goe(createdAtParam)).set(createdAtParam, startCreatedDate);
        }
        if (Objects.nonNull(endCreatedDate)) {
            ParamExpression<ZonedDateTime> endedAtParam = new ParamExpressionImpl<>(ZonedDateTime.class);
            query = query.where(qCoupon.createdAt.loe(endedAtParam)).set(endedAtParam, endCreatedDate);
        }
        ......
       final String queryString = query.toString();
       final TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, Object[].class)
                .setFirstResult(pageRequest.getOffset())
                .setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize());


        for (Map.Entry<ParamExpression<?>, Object> paramExpressionObjectEntry : query.getMetadata().getParams().entrySet()) {
            ParamExpression<?> paramExpression = paramExpressionObjectEntry.getKey();
            typedQuery.setParameter(paramExpression.getName(), paramExpressionObjectEntry.getValue());
        }

        List<Object[]> queryResult = typedQuery
                .getResultList();
```

The problem is the `queryString` variable contains unnamed parameter like `where lower(coupon.code) like lower(?1)` not as expected with named parameter that starts with `:`. I've tried using name, adding second constructor argument in `ParamExpressionImpl` like `new ParamExpressionImpl<>(String.class, qCoupon.code.getMetadata().getName())` it's just same.

As a result it returns with exception message `Parameter with that name [code] did not exist`.
How's the correct use of QueryDSL's `ParamExpression` on the `typedQuery.setParameter(...)` line?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ParamExpressionImpl` you should use `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Param`, which also takes a String argument which will be the name of the parameter (`:parameter`).